# How to manage AWS configs with environment variables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a couple of Beanstalk services running on AWS and each one requires a set of environment variables to be configured. What's the ideal way to manage this outside of manually going in and plugging them in by hand?

Answer (score 0):

I see that it is clearly documented here,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-methods-during.html

> aws elasticbeanstalk create-environment --application-name my-app
>   --environment-name my-env --version-label v1 --template-name savedconfig --option-settings file://healthcheckurl.json

Hope it helps.

Comment: The question is less about EB and more about how to manage configuration. Considering placing settings in git for staging and production are anti-patterns I'm curious what the best practices are around managing them?

Comment: @Art Who says placing settings in git for staging and production is anti-pattern? and why? Is your Git environment open to the internet?

Comment: See: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/205606/strategy-for-keeping-secret-info-such-as-api-keys-out-of-source-control